# jQuery Plugins triggerable by Console, but not by function - why that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, activation

I have a mysterious JS Problem: I activate different jQuery-Plugins with one function. It's called like this:

```
<script>
postAjaxCalls();
</script>
```

Then, the corresponding function looks like this:

```
function postAjaxCalls() {
    jQuery("[title]").tooltip(); 
    alert("this works great, tooltip not!");
    jQuery("select").selectbox();
}
```

When I reload the page, everything works but the tooltip plugin. Now, if I fire the exact same Code into the JS Console, the plugin is activated:

```
jQuery("[title]").tooltip();
```

Why that? Why does it work when activated via console, but doesn't work when activated via a function?

Cheers!

Comment: Trying putting it inside a document.ready

Comment: see comment to codeparadox: getting it anyways.. ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your code within `$(document).ready(function() {  ..  })` in short `$(function() { .. })` to execute your code after DOM ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  function postAjaxCalls() {
    jQuery("[title]").tooltip(); 
    alert("this works great, tooltip not!");
    jQuery("select").selectbox();
  } 
  postAjaxCalls();

});
```

OR in short

```
jQuery(function() {

  function postAjaxCalls() {
    jQuery("[title]").tooltip(); 
    alert("this works great, tooltip not!");
    jQuery("select").selectbox();
  } 
  postAjaxCalls();

});
```

Comment: that's paradox: I got that problem with another project as well. I use your advice (jQuery(function() {..})), but it still doesnt work until I execute $('.datepicker').datepicker(); in console!?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling `postAjaxCalls` before the DOM is ready.  When you call it from the console, the DOM is ready, so it works.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    postAjaxCalls();
});
```